# How to access "this" (or $state) object in "data" attribute of the same .state() of $stateProvider

Tags: angularjs

I'm using `$stateProvider` for routing in my application. For some requirement, I'd like to use `this` (or `$state` itself) to read data of self `.state()`, in the `data` attribute, as in below.

```
...
.state(<state_name>, {
    url: <path>,
    views: {
        <view_name>: {
            templateUrl: <template_url>,
            controller: <controller_name>
        }
    },
    data: {
        selfStateData: (function() {
            return this;
        })()
    }
})
...
```

When checked for the above returned value by `console.log()` in `$stateChangeSuccess`, I'm receiving `undefined`.

Please help.

Comment: any reason why you want to return `$state` itself? Maybe there is a better solution for your problem, e.g. `$stateParams` or something with `$transition` service

Comment: Its for authentication purpose, only authenticated users should be able to access the particular states (paths). I have user-roles specific to each state (or path in it), receiving from the back-end. So, I'd like to set the user-role for each state in `data` attribute **dynamically** (with anonymous method in `data` attribute, which will have some logic). So that, I can use it (`data` attribute) in `$steateChangeSuccess`, to prevent unauthenticated accesses to the states.

Comment: I think it's best to use `resolve` for this. Just call some function (from a service) inside your resolve and return user role, which you then can accept of reject, preventing the access to some page. Then the page won't even load if the roles do not match. e.g. `resolve: { userData: function resolveUser(YourService){ return YourService.canAccess(['guest','user','admin']) } }`

Comment: Ok @AlekseySolovey, I'll try this.
BTW, still, Is it possible to hold `this` (current object), in any of `data` or `resolve` attribute? So that some logic could be written using/with the self `.state()`'s data, for any future requirements.

Comment: your future requirements might also have a different solution that you are not aware of

Answer (score 0):

Check if `.resolve()` holds `this` and update the `data` attribute in the same `.state()`.